# Fix position of Label

Tags: xaml, button, label

I have two buttons on either side of a `Label`.
If either of these `Button`s get removed, I want the `Label` to stay centered in a fixed position.

Is there any way to lock the position of this `Label`?

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="4,8,4,8" LastChildFill="True">
        <Button Name="SearchBackButton" Style="{DynamicResourceInfoButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource SearchBackButton}"  
          VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="SearchBackButton_Click" />
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="HelveticaNeue"   FontSize="14" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#273238" Name="SuggestedTemplatesText" Content="{x:Static res:UIStrings.SuggestedTemplates}"/>
        <Button Name="info_icon" Style="{DynamicResource InfoButtonStyle}" Click="InfoButton_Click"  
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>       <!-- Added by edit -->
```

This is the code for the `Label` and the two `Button`s.

[image]